# MYSQL error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s) on insert statement (no selects)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm using MYSQL version 5.7 and this is the table giving me issues:

```
CREATE TABLE Tenencia(
  fechaInicio DATE,
  numero INT,
  nif CHAR(10),
  fechaFinal DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (fechaInicio,numero,nif),
  FOREIGN KEY (numero) REFERENCES Animal (numero)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (nif) REFERENCES Propietario (nif)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```

I'm trying to do a simple insertion of data into this table, like so:

```
INSERT INTO Tenencia (fechaInicio,numero,nif,fechaFinal) 
VALUES ('2012-06-10', 2, '1B', '2012-09-11');
```

But it's returning this error:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I've seen this question asked before when SELECTs are used in the insertion, or when trying to insert multiple rows at a time, but I'm inserting them one by one (it's a class assignment and inserting them one by one is one of the requirements).

[Here's a link to the complete script](http://pastebin.com/AjyV0LwX), if that's necessary.
In the table definition there is a trigger as well.

Help please!

Comment: This can't be the query causing the said issue

Comment: Please post a reproducible sample which generates this error.

Comment: @Rahul The INSERT I wrote above is literally the only thing I'm writing on the command line! Tables have already been created by this point, and I've already successfully inserted data into the referenced tables Animal and Propietario.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/AjyV0LwX) to the full script to create the database, it tries to insert a bunch of rows into Tenencia, and it throws the error.

Comment: Don't give us a link but rather include this information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your trigger script:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ttenenciaUnica
  BEFORE INSERT ON Tenencia
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
  IF (NEW.fechaFinal IS NULL) AND (SELECT * FROM Tenencia T
                    WHERE T.numero = NEW.numero AND T.fechaFinal IS  NULL) THEN
    set msg = "Animal ya inscrito en una Tenencia activa.";
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
  END IF;
```

if you remove it you will be able to insert, the wrong command is:

```
SELECT * FROM Tenencia T WHERE T.numero = NEW.numero AND T.fechaFinal IS  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `( SELECT * ... )` try `EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )`.